# SSIS - SQL Update Query without output: Error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-update, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to run an update query in the middle of the SSIS package and doing it via SQL rather than using all of the built in logic gates is preferred to avoid the headache. The issue I'm running into is that if I return no results, it gives me an error:

```
Error 1 Validation error. No column information was returned by the SQL command.
```

Locally I originally had:

```
SELECT 1 [placeholder]
```

at the end of my query to trick it into executing, but when I imported this package to SQL Server as a job to automate, it skipped this update because SELECT 1 [placeholder] is never used so it views it was "unnecessary code":

```
Error: Update has been removed from the Data Flow task because its output is not used and its inputs either have no side effects or are not connected to outputs of other components. If the component is required, then the HasSideEffects property on at least one of its inputs should be set to true, or its output should be connected to something.
```

So I turned to my SSIS package and went to set **HasSideEffects** = True, but it's greyed out and won't let me change it, so now I'm unsure what to do. How can I resolve this without using the built in logic gates? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: in SSIS your running a SQL script task and it is giving you that error?  If so should just have to update inside the script task box a box that says result set = false

Comment: I don't see a result set box that I can toggle true/false. I looked at varying levels per the update and am not seeing it. I'm using an OLD DB Source if that matters. Should I be using something else to perform an Update statement?

Comment: Sorry it is ResultSet -  NONE  (not true false)  Are you using at the Execute SQL Task Editor?  Looks like this  https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/imported/1586-Figure9-6f69fff2-e1d8-4bb6-91a2-ffdca2bbc586.jpg

Comment: Oh! I'm an idiot! Thanks Brad! I should be using Execute SQL Task. I was using Data Flow Task, hence why it was expecting a result or flow of some sort. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Brad's help, realized I need to use "Execute SQL Task" not "Data Flow Task".

Comment: Had the same problem. You have to go in the "Control Flow" section instead of "Data Flow". Then the "Execute SQL Task" appears in the toolbox.